# How to hide an api key in AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, key, hide

I would like to done an ajax request directly done by client on desktop.

Problem is my ajax request need a "secret api Key". I don't want the client has an access to this api key.

Here my currently js code:

```
    var url = 'myurl';                
    var obj = new Object();
    obj.api_key         = "myKeyIwantToHide";
    $.ajax({    url: url, 
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: obj,
                cache: false,
                success: function(result){
                    alert(result);
                }
    });
```

It is possible to hide information to client with javascript in order to done my ajax request.

Thx,
Christophe

Comment: You cannot hide anything in JavaScript client sided.

Comment: If it's sent to the client, the client has access. If you need to keep the key secret you'll have to create a proxy on your own server.

Comment: If you have control of the server you should look into using JWT for authentication.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot hide the api key completely from client. But if your client is non technical. You can make it hard for him/her to find api key. If you are using MVC you can set the api key when the first request is sent to the Index method and on return you can set it to a javascript variable. In this way user wont be able to see hardcoded value unlike in the code you have shown. If you are using ASP.NET then you can easily use ViewBag to set value to javascript variable using razor syntax.

Comment: Assuming stuff like "but if your client is non technical." is kinda a bad practice to have while programming...